# How can i get all bound RMI Stubs with their url?

Tags: java, url, registry, rmi, stubs

is it possible to get all bound Stubs (hope this is right) and their url? Is that possible?

To improve my Question i give you a Code sample like:

(Binding)

```
    Registry registry = LocateRegistry.createRegistry(1099);
    registry.bind(url+"//ServiceX", new RMIServiceX());
```

(my attempt)

```
registry.getAllBinds
```

or

```
registry.getAllUrl
```

I only need something to test my Url and Stubs. I hope im not to far from Reality.

Im very Thankfull for every comment or Answer i get.

Answer (score 1):

Just call list() to get all the URLs, and then for each URL call lookup() to get the corresponding stub.

Comment: Is it Possible to make this through client side? Im very new to rmi pls be gentle.

Comment: You don't seem to be making any kind of an effort here. This is all documented. You could always try it.